# Making a has_many relation avoiding childs to store paretn's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :favorites, class_name: "Item"
end

class Item
 include Mongoid::Document
 belongs_to :user, dependent: :nullify

end
```

I want that the users have an array of favorites but in Item collection, the user_id is not stored. Is the approach I followed correct?

If I try to access a user favorites as `User.last.favourites` or try to add a favorite to a user, it takes for ever. Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the `embedded_in :user` on your `Item` class

Comment: Shit sorry I misread your first post. Have you used something like RoboMongo to see what data is being persisted? The has many may be storing an array of ids that correspond to the items. I would check that out. Try to look in your server logs to see what the query looks like. I have little experience with Mongoid

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :favorites, class_name: "Item"
end

class Item
 # class is all lower case
 include Mongoid::Document
 # remove the relation to the user form the item
 # so that it cannot save the user_id 
end
```

the previous code should work, and won't allow you to save the user_id in a favorite.

so this code should work `user.last.favorites #=> [Array of favorites]`
but this code will through an exception `user.last.favorites.last.user #=> method user not found`

- why it takes forever ?! I cannot judge unless i've seen the logs.

also don't go for the embedded solution, the embedded collection is only accessible from the parent... and i think this is not what you want to achieve...

in a simpler words: if you have a favorite that is called 'rails',
using the embedded solution described in the other answer would result in the following behaviour

```
p Favorites.all.to_a
#=> []
p user.first.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 1, name: rails>
p user.last.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 100, name: rails>
```

if you noticed:

- the collections is not query-able except from the parent that embeds it.
- the favorites collections is unique per user. 2 different users cannot share the same embedded document ( as in the previous code, both first and last user has the same favorite (what you intended) but they are actually 2 completely different objects.

the same code using the `has_many` relation would result in the following

```
p Favorites.all.to_a
#=> [<<Favorite id: 1, name: rails>]
p user.first.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 1, name: rails>
p user.last.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 1, name: rails>

# this is pseudocode but you will get the idea
user.last.favorites.first.name = `rails4` # then save

p user.first.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 1, name: rails4>
p user.last.favorites.first
#=> <Favorite id: 1, name: rails4>
```